# How to change form1 propreties or it's object properties from another winform?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I cannot access to my main form's properties or it's object's properties from secondary form that open from `Form1`.

Is there a simple way so solve this problem?

I have found several and useless solutions in the net.

Comment: What is your code? What have you tried so far? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: Is the problem that you can't access Form1 at all?

Comment: simple (if maybe not best practice) solution: have the constructor of your secondary form get a reference to your main form. and access its properties from there.

Answer (score 0):

Set the properties of the `Form1` to public but note, that this breaks OOP rules

Comment: I cannot call them directly.How should I call them?

Answer (score 0):

Set one or more public properties in your MainForm. When opening the second Form, set the owner of that form to the MainForm. This way, you can access the properties of the MainForm in the second form. Example code:

Code-behind Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public String SomeProperty { get; set; }

    //Event of a normal button with name 'OpenFormButton'
    private void OpenFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var secondForm = new Form2
        {
            Owner = this
        };
        secondForm.Show();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SomeProperty = "HELLO WORLD";
    }
}
```

Code-behind Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var owner = this.Owner as Form1;
        var val = owner.SomeProperty;
        MessageBox.Show(val); //Shows a MessageBox with 'HELLO WORLD'
    }
}
```

This is just a simple code to show how you can access properties on another form. Instead of only getting the value of the property, you can also set (change) the value of the property. This also goes for complex types instead of strings and integers. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an instance of Form1 to Form2 constructor

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the using of a simple Callback function like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public String SomeProperty { get; set; }

    private void OpenFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var secondForm = new Form2()
        {
            GetSomeProperty = () => { return SomeProperty ;};
        };
        secondForm.Show();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SomeProperty = "HELLO WORLD";
    }
}



public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Func<string> GetSomeProperty
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(GetSomeProperty.Invoke());
    }
}
```

Everytime you call
GetSomeProperty.Invoke();
the Func will call the get accessor and return it from the first Form